# iOS 5 exc_bad_access code=2 with CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, uiview, exc-bad-access, cabasicanimation

I'm getting this error:

[image]

With this code:

```
-(void)lowerGUI {
[mainGUI.layer addAnimation:guiLower forKey:@"transform.translation.y"];
```

}

I have a UIView which I'm animating up and down to move it out of the way if needed.  I've set up my animation in viewDidLoad:

```
guiLower = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
guiLower.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
guiLower.duration = 1;
guiLower.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:320];
guiLower.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:481];
```

The code builds and runs fine, but when I click the button to run the animation, the error appears.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using ARC? is `guiLower` a property?

Comment: No to ARC, guiLower is a CABasicAnimation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that you should hold a reference to your animation:

```
guiLower = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
```

in an ivar or property of your class and make sure that the object you assign to it is properly retained. Indeed, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is commonly caused by accessing an already deallocated instance of an object.

Example:

in .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CABasicAnimation* guiLower;
```

in .m file:

```
@synthesize guiLower;

...

self.guiLower = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
...
```

Comment: That sorted it, thank you.  The animation doesn't animate, but that's a different matter.  It's instant, it ignores the timing.  But hey ho :)

Comment: As an update, in the end I did a simple UIView animation, made more sense for something so simple.